# What is the best way to show the speed of copying files on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, catalina, performance, copy-paste

I'm using macbookpro 16inch, Catalina 10.15.5 . I connect to my external SSD drive (SAMSUNG T5) from usb-C to usb-C. When using drag and drop in finder , it took 5 sec to copy a 1,47 Gb file. I need to see the writing speed while i'm copying (like in windows) so i use rsync command :

```
rsync -a --progress --stats --human-readable <path_to_source> <path_to_dest>
```

The problem is with rsync, it took surprisingly slower to finish the copy, about 7 or 8 sec. I repeated it many times and got the same result. Any idea what happen ? is there any other better and reliable way to see the writing speed while copying  ?

Thanks